# NullPointerException onBackpressed (Fragment to Activity) Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I get a NullPointerException everytime I use the back button at actionbar from RouteView Activity (which uses fragments) to RouteChoose Activity. The problem - where I get the Nullpointer - is the following value at RouteChoose at OnCreate:

```
citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
```

I don´t know why I get a Nullpointer, if I use the back button at actionbar (parent activity), but I get no Nullpointer, if I use the back button on my phone. I also get no NullPointer, if I use the actionbar menu item point. How have I to call the little back arrow an the left side at actionbar to send an Intent?

P.S.: If anyone has a hint, how to simplify the if else condition to prevent the redundant code, you´re welcome :)

RouteChoose:

```
public class RouteChooseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    Integer citySave;
    Integer routeSave;
    String cityTitle;
    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> cities;
    CityParser parser = new CityParser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
        TextView headingRoute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeTitel);
        headingRoute.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.route_text)) + " " + cityTitle + " aus:");
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRoute);
        if (citySave.equals(1)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_passau.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (citySave.equals(2)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_bamberg.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (citySave.equals(3)) {
            try {
                cities = parser.parse(getAssets().open("route_augsburg.xml"));
                CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_items, (ArrayList<RowItem>) cities);
                Collections.sort(cities, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                    public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                        return s1.getTitle().compareTo(s2.getTitle());
                    }
                });
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                TextView errorMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeTitel);
                errorMessage.setText(R.string.errorroute);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.errorroute);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        setTitle("Routen in" + " " + cityTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(RouteChooseActivity.this, RouteView.class);
        RowItem cities = (RowItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        b.putInt("route", cities.getID());
        b.putString("titel_route", cities.getTitle());
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
        savedInstanceState.putInt("stadt", citySave);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
        citySave = savedInstanceState.getInt("stadt");
        Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + citySave);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
            cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.Bild));
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.Bild));
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view)
    {
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.route, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_stadt:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stadt);
                Intent stadt = new Intent(RouteChooseActivity.this, StadtActivity.class);
                startActivity(stadt);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
                Intent help = new Intent(RouteChooseActivity.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(help);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

RouteView:

```
public class RouteView extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     *
     */

    Integer citySave;
    String cityTitle;
    Integer routeSave;
    String routeTitel;
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<RowItem> pois;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_view);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        cityTitle = b.getString("titel_stadt");
        routeSave = b.getInt("route");
        routeTitel = b.getString("titel_route");
        b.putString("titel_route",routeTitel);
        b.putInt("route", routeSave);
        //RouteItemFragment fragobj = new RouteItemFragment();
        //fragobj.setArguments(b);




        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        setTitle("Route:" + " " + routeTitel);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.route_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return RouteItemFragment.newInstance(position);
                case 1:
                    return MapFragment.newInstance(position);
                default:
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class RouteItemFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        ListView listView;
        List<RowItem> pois;
        Integer routeSave;
        String routeTitel;
        private View rootView;

        public static RouteItemFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            RouteItemFragment fragment = new RouteItemFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public RouteItemFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            routeSave = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("route");
            routeTitel = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("titel_route");


            //pois  = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("pois");

            if (routeSave.equals(1)) {
                try {
                    PoiParser parser = new PoiParser();
                    pois = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("poi_passau1.xml"));
                    CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_items, pois);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Collections.sort(pois, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                        public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                            return s1.getID() - s2.getID();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (routeSave.equals(2)){
                try {
                    PoiParser parser = new PoiParser();
                    pois = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("poi_passau1.xml"));
                    CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_items, pois);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Collections.sort(pois, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                        public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                            return s1.getID() - s2.getID();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (routeSave.equals(7)){
                try {
                    PoiParser parser = new PoiParser();
                    pois = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("poi_passau1.xml"));
                    CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_items, pois);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Collections.sort(pois, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                        public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                            return s1.getID() - s2.getID();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (routeSave.equals(8)){
                try {
                    PoiParser parser = new PoiParser();
                    pois = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("poi_passau1.xml"));
                    CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_items, pois);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Collections.sort(pois, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                        public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                            return s1.getID() - s2.getID();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (routeSave.equals(9)){
                try {
                    PoiParser parser = new PoiParser();
                    pois = parser.parse(getActivity().getAssets().open("poi_passau1.xml"));
                    CityListViewAdapter adapter = new CityListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_items, pois);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Collections.sort(pois, new Comparator<RowItem>() {
                        public int compare(RowItem s1, RowItem s2) {
                            return s1.getID() - s2.getID();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                    try {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textRouteitem);
                        textView.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.errorroute)));
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.errorroute);
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();

                }
            }
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelableArrayList("pois", (ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>) pois);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            rootView = null; // now cleaning up!
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route_item, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textRouteitem);
            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            textView.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.routeViewfragment)) + " "
                    + getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("titel_route"));
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View parent, int position, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), PoiView.class);
            RowItem pois = (RowItem) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("stadt", pois.getID());
            b.putParcelableArrayList("pois", pois);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putString("titel_stadt", cityTitle);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("stadt", citySave);
        b.putInt("route", routeSave);
        b.putString("route_titel",routeTitel);
        finish();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        citySave = b.getInt("stadt");
        routeSave = b.getInt("route");
        routeTitel = b.getString("route_titel");

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_stadt:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_stadt);
                Intent stadt = new Intent(RouteView.this, StadtActivity.class);
                startActivity(stadt);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_route:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
                Intent route = new Intent(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                route.putExtra("stadt", citySave);
                route.putExtra("stadt_titel", cityTitle);
                startActivity(route);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_help:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
                Intent help = new Intent(RouteView.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(help);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.cityknight.app/de.cityknight.app.RouteChooseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at de.cityknight.app.RouteChooseActivity.onCreate(RouteChooseActivity.java:44)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I´ve added the logcat, but had to delete some code, cause to much signs...

Comment: you have a missunderstant backbutton is the back button build on your phone, home button is the button on the actionbar that usually go backwords navegation, the first one you get controll overriding hook onPressBackButton, second one on OnOptionsItemSelected and in the case android.R.id.home, is not easy to undersatant your explantion.

Comment: Thanks, but how does an example code look like - I´ve found something at Google, but it doesn´t work til now: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not passed any value with your intents in these sections:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_stadt:
            Intent stadt = new Intent(RouteView.this, StadtActivity.class);
            startActivity(stadt);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_route:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_choose);
            Intent route = new Intent(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
            startActivity(route);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_help:
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);
            Intent help = new Intent(RouteView.this, Help.class);
            startActivity(help);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_exit:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

you must do something like this:

```
 Intent route = new Intent(RouteView.this, RouteChooseActivity.class);
 route .putExtra("stadt", citySave);
 startActivity(route);
```

Comment: Thanks I´ve added a bundle: Bundle b = new Bundle(); b.putInt("stadt", citySave); at case R.id.action_route But I get already a NullPointer.

Comment: Yes. Example: <activity
            android:name=".RouteChooseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_route"
            android:parentActivityName=".StadtActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="StadtActivity" />
        </activity>
Can you pls add an edit of your answer with one example, how a working code should look like.

Comment: thanks, but at this case the method putInt cannot be resolved - I think a bundle is needed all time, isn´t it?

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: Nothing happens. If you mean ctrl o I get a new window at android studio: select methods to override, but putint is not available.

Comment: sorry i think you are using eclipse, does this exist  import android.content.Intent;

Comment: Hm no, cause I´ven´t such a class. Only android.content.Context and a few other.

Comment: hey this is not your class, this is class of intent object that google provide for you, add it

Comment: Ok, hmm strange at import I´ve already got: import android.content.Intent;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58870/discussion-between-mmlooloo-and-ben).